# .NET CORE 3.1 ERROR 500 during WebSocket handshake

Tags: apache, ubuntu, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using SignalR on my **.net core 3.1** API and it all works on localhost

hosting my app on ubuntu 20.4 will result in error 500 during handshake...

**I am pretty sure I am missing something on my Apache configs**...

error is just "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500" no extra data although -> options.EnableDetailedErrors = true

any idea why it doesn't work?
this my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

    }).AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    // Configure Compression level
    services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

    // Add Response compression services
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
    });

    services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();


    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,

        // ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };

    jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());


   
    services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });


    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IDistributedCache cache)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<AnalyticsHub>("/AnalyticsHub");
        endpoints.MapHub<CampaignHub>("/CampaignHub");
        endpoints.MapHub<LinkHub>("/LinkHub");
    });


    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

the error:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @David Muns,try to [allow the credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests).

Comment: same result....

Comment: **HTTP 500** Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. You could post codes of "/CampaignHub" to get further help.